# Object Oriented JavaScript programming

Tags: javascript, oop

I have been trying to learn OOP with JavaScript before I start attempting to learn backbone.js.

I want to be able to data bind but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've just made a simple protoype of a budget website that you can put in a budget and input how much you've spent, and it will show if you've gone over.

```
function BudgetItem(spent, budget){

    this.setSpent = function(spent){
        this.spent = spent;
    }
    this.setBudget = function(budget){
        this.budget = budget;
    }
    this.getSpent = function(){
        return this.spent;
    }
    this.getBudget = function(){
        return this.budget;
    }

}

function BudgetType(type){
    this.getType = function(){
        return type;
    }
}

BudgetType.prototype = new BudgetItem();

$(document).ready(function(){

    var food = new BudgetType('food');

    $('.budget').html(food.getBudget());
    $('.editbudget').change(function(){
        food.setBudget($('.editbudget').data())
    });
})
```

That's my code thus far. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Am I supposed to extend things? Also, can someone explain how to dynamically data bind without a library?

Comment: You don't need the braindead getter/setter functions, if you require additional functionality in them later, you can always add them afterwards as getter/setter properties and it will work the same in public interface

Comment: First off, I'd suggest NOT using jQuery or such librarys until you have a FIRM understanding of JS.

Comment: This does not answer your question but if you are trying to get a good handle on JS, OOP or otherwise, you should definitely read [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596517742/wrrrldwideweb) by [Douglas Crockford](http://crockford.com/).

Comment: @Esailija what do you mean by braindead? why would these not be useful, if i want to populate an element with that data?

Comment: @SReject I'm currently halfway through a JS course and would ask why not to?

Comment: @eggmaster, mainly because there's far too many that "know jQuery but not javascript". IMO, it's foolish to to purchase a faster motor when a person doesn't understand how to drive the car.

Comment: @eggmaster because it's exactly the same as directly setting or getting the property

Comment: The line '`BudgetType.prototype = new BudgetItem();`' means that every BudgetType **is** a BudgetItem.  The names suggest that every BudgetItem **has** a BudgetType.  If that's what you want, then you need some rework, regardless of the concerns about jQuery or getters/setters.

Comment: updated my answer w/ two possibilities: sharing members via reference between all objects, or building objects from a 'base'

Comment: I think you can get some better answers if you clarify what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I'll give you some theory. A Javascript function is a dynamic object, just like `Object` is, and a new instance can be created using the `new` keyword much like you are doing in your listener. When this happens, the function itself will run as a constructor while the `this` keyword will be bound to the newly created object. What you're doing above then is in fact adding new properties on the fly as you're passing in their values for the first time... which is fine, but not very clear to another reader.

Now for the tricky part. Every function has a link to a "hidden" Prototype object. This is an anonymous (not accessible by name) object created by the JavaScript runtime and passed as a reference to the user object through the `prototype` property. This Prototype object also has a reference to the function through its `constructor` property. To test what I'm saying for yourself, try the following:

```
BudgetItem.prototype.constructor === BudgetItem // true
```

Putting it all together, you can now think of functions as constructors to (hidden) classes that are created for you behind the scenes, accessible through the function's prototype property. So, you could add the fields to the Prototype object directly as so:

```
function BudgetItem(spent) { 
    this.spent = spent 
}           
BudgetItem.prototype.setSpent = function(spent) { this.spent = spent };
BudgetItem.prototype.getSpent = function() { return this.spent };
```

Another problem is inheritance and passing parameters to the constructor. Again, your version is valid but you lose the ability to pass the spent and budget values when initializing a BudgetType. What I would do is forget prototypes and go:

```
function BudgetType(type, spent) {
    var instance = new BudgetItem(spent);
    instance.type = type;
    return instance;
}
```

This is close to what Scott Sauyet suggested above but more powerful. Now you can pass both parameters (and more) and have a more complicated inheritance tree.

Finally, what you can do is create private (or pseudo-private, more accurately) properties by providing a getter to an otherwise automatic variable (one passed as an argument or initialised inside the function). This is a special feature of the language and it works like so:

```
function BudgetType(type, spent) {
     var instance = new BudgetItem(spent);
     instance.getType = function() {
         return type;
     }
     return instance;
}
```

Now you can access the 'type' passed in the constructor by obj.getType() but cannot override the initial value. Even if you define obj.type = 'New Value' the getType() will return the initial parameter passed because it has a reference to another context which was created when the object was initialised and never got released due to the closure.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

if you want all instances of objects to reference the same members/values you can use a closure:

```
// create a constrctor for you object wrapped in a closure
myCon = (function() {

    // define shared members up here
    var mySharedObj = new function () {
        this.member = "a";
    }();

    // return the actual constructor   
    return function () {
        this.mySharedObj = mySharedObj;
    }
}());

// create two instances of the object
var a = new myCon();
var b = new myCon();


// Altering the shared object from one
a.mySharedObj.member = "b";

// Alters it for all
console.log(b.mySharedObj.member);
```

If you want to build objects from other objects(sort of like other languages' `class whatever extends baseClass`), but do not want them to share values via reference(instead a clone of values), you can use something like the following:

```
Object.prototype.extendsUpon = (function (_prop, _args) {
    return function (base) {
        for (var key in base) {
            if (_prop.call(base, key)) {
                this[key] = base[key];
            }
        }

        function con(child){
            this.constructor = child;
        }
        con.prototype = base.prototype;

        this.prototype = new con(this);
        this.__base__ = base.prototype;

        var args = _args.call(arguments);
        args.shift();
        base.constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
}(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, Array.prototype.slice));
```

Then to build objects ontop of objects:

```
// Base Object Constructor
function Fruit(name) {
    this.fruitname = name;
}
Fruit.prototype.yum = function() {
    return "I had an " + this.fruitname;
}

// Object constructor that derives from the Base Object
function Favorite() {

    // Derive this object from a specified base object:
    //     @arg0  -> Object Constructor to use as base
    //     @arg1+ -> arguments passed to the BaseObject's constructor
    this.extendsUpon(Fruit, "apple");

    // From here proceed as usual

    // To access members from the base object that have been over-written,
    // use "this.__base__.MEMBER.apply(this, arguments)"
}
Favorite.prototype.yum = function() {
    return this.__base__.yum.apply(this) + " and it was my favorite";
}
var mmm = new Favorite();

// Outputs: "I had an apple and it was my favorite" 
mmm.yum();
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing for me but I will work on it, however it's very informative, I appreciate your time, thank you!!